# Trying (and failing) to use custom image for Google Maps marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong...I can get "marker" to show up, with just the standard orange/red marker, but I am trying to get the "starbucks" marker to show up with a custom image. My map appears but not the second marker. Where am I slipping up?
Here's my code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>

function initialize() {
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.7442357,-118.015271);
var image = 'images/coffee.png';
 var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 17,
 center: myLatlng
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);


var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Business Name'

});

var starbucks = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.744236,-118.015271),
  map: map,
  icon: image,
  title: 'Starbucks'

});

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Comment: What is "image"?  Does it exist at that relative path on your server/machine?

Comment: [this works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_starbucksIcon.html) (your code, plus an inline icon)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have this image in the right place:

```
var image = 'images/coffee.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to debug, try following and see if your custom marker shows up:

```
var starbucks = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.744236,-118.015271),
  map: map,
  icon: 'images/coffee.png',
  title: 'Starbucks'

 });
```